# Tag changes it value

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, tags

I don't understand why the tag equal 0 for the third times.

```
UIButton *b1;
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    b1 =[[UIButton alloc] init];
    b1.tag = 1;
    NSLog(@"Button pressed: %d", b1.tag); // tag = 1
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)funcA:(id)sender // I create mannualy the button b1
{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed 2nd: %d", b1.tag); // tag = 1
    b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
b1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
[b1 setTitle:@"b1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:b1];
[b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(funcB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];

}
-(void)funcB:(id)sender //the func of B1
{
    NSLog(@"Button 3rd %d", b1.tag); // here the tag = 0


}
```

I hope what I have requested is possible. ^^

Comment: Sorry but b1 is at the top, i just fail. So If B1 is a global variable, is it good ?
And I don't understand the problem c :
There are three buttons bind one Action, I try to differentiate which button has been pressed by the user and for this, I use their tag.

Comment: If you have three different buttons all calling the same action method, you can either (a) give the three views separate `tag` values and (b) look at the `sender` parameter, which will reference which button was pressed. In answer to your question, if it really was global variable, that's probably not a good idea. If you had separate instance variable (or better, a property) of the class for each button, then that's fine if you need to keep a reference to it for future purposes.

Comment: Yes, i don't have choice, I made me do a property.
Thank you for your help. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do that:

```
b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

You are making a new button.

You can change your code for that:

```
UIButton *b1;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  b1.tag = 1;
  b1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
  [b1 setTitle:@"b1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  NSLog(@"Button pressed: %d", b1.tag); // tag = 1
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
}
- (void)funcA:(id)sender // I create mannualy the button b1
{
  NSLog(@"Button pressed 2nd: %d", b1.tag); // tag = 1
  [b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(funcB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
  [self.view addSubview:b1];

}
-(void)funcB:(id)sender //the func of B1
{
   NSLog(@"Button 3rd %d", b1.tag); // here the tag = 1
}
```

Comment: But if i don't write it, the button doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad`, you are creating a button, but not saving it anywhere (you're not using the `b1` instance variable, but rather have a local variable that coincidentally has the name name) and not adding it to any view, and thus it will be released when the function finishes.

In `funcA`, you're instantiating a completely different button (not the one that the user pressed, not the one that was created and discarded in `viewDidLoad`). You also never set the `tag` for this new button. (Frankly, it's unclear what's calling `funcA` at all; do you have a button on your storyboard or something like that?!?)

Bottom line, if you want `funcB` to show the `tag` for the button you created in `funcA`, then you have to set the `tag` for the button in `funk`.

---

In `funcB`, it is useful to reference the `sender` to identify which button was pressed, e.g.:

```
- (void)createButton
{
    b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    b1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
    b1.tag = 42;
    [b1 setTitle:@"b1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:b1];
    [b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(funcB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)funcB:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button tag %d", sender.tag);  // the answer is 42
}
```